How can I plot ground tracks on the surface of the Moon?
I'm curious if there's a module or Python library capable of plotting ground tracks on the Moon's surface, similar to how Skyfield or Astropy functions. I understand that Two-Line Elements (TLEs) are utilized as input, and SGP4 propagates these mean elements. However, as far as I know, SGP4 is primarily used to account for perturbations in Earth's environment but for the moon. My main goal is to crear a single ground track on Moon's surface using a propagation method.

As you indicated, you cannot use SGP4 in other than earths orbit (unless you rewrite much of its code). As a first shot, I would recommend you, to use basic keplerian elements. Just google how to visualize it and transfer it 1to1 on a moon map. But have in mind, main perturbations in a lunar orbit are due to moons unshapely gravitational potential. So for longer spans or more accurate visualization you may need a numerical propagator.

@CallMeTom As you mentioned, I was planning to start using basic Keplerian elements and coordinate transformations similar to perifocal PQW, ECI, and ECEF. However, I don't have much knowledge about lunar perturbations or access to raw data concerning them in general.

GRAIL MOON LGRS DERIVED GRAVITY SCIENCE DATA PRODUCTS

Do have a particular satellite in mind? Horizons can propagate TLE data for Earth satellites, but it doesn't offer an equivalent service for the Moon. OTOH, it has trajectory data for the LRO https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/api/horizons.api?format=text&MAKE_EPHEM=NO&COMMAND=lro I assume that trajectory uses the spherical harmonics from Grail, but perhaps it doesn't...

@PM2Ring I was thinking of testing first with a hypothetical satellite using my own parameters.
